# Can I create an app which does not follow apple restrictions if I am not going to release it?

Tags: ios, notifications, app-store, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to create an app that can be run in the background mode whenever a Bluetooth (LE) connection is available. This app also should generate local notifications on the background mode, which are based on what data the Bluetooth sends to it.
The problem is that the Bluetooth device must be MPi(made for iPhone) to make the app constantly get data from it. My BLE module is HM-10, which is not MPi.
Can I create an app that constantly connects to the Bluetooth LE and sends notifications if I am not going to release the app in AppStore
for now?
And if I decide the release, is there any ways to get around this problem?

Comment: if your not going to release it...do whatever you want

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Let me ask a question to make sure. Does the XCode allow me to run the app on the background and send the notifications for indefinitely?

Comment: The restrictions that you have are built in to the OS, so unless you jailbreak the phone the same limitations mostly apply. There are some things that you can implement (maybe using private API's etc) that Apple would reject during the review process that you can get away with if they aren't going to be reviewing it

Comment: Could you give me some suggestions on how can I make the app indefinitely work on the background and send notifications with the help of my Bluetooth LE device?

Comment: You can't make it do that... only the supported background modes. maybe by doing location updates?

Comment: Location updates are going to take too much time to process the information and they are not going to connect my phone to the Bluetooth LE device so I guess I should come up with another method or somehow certify the BLE module?

Comment: yeah, the point is background mode is restricted. you only get a short amount of time. Apple say you cannot do it.

Comment: Thank you, very much! Your comments are extremely useful to me!